# Read multiple csv file and insert data in oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I want to read multiple csv files from a folder and insert data in oracle table. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SQL*Loader](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/part_ldr.htm) to load `CSV` data into oracle tables.